# Is there a way to disable MS Word 2010's file close (ctrl+w) short cut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

There was a mishap where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> was pressed on a long document that wasn't saved yet, and all of that unsaved work was gone. Is there a way to disable MS Word 2010's file close short cut?

Comment: If you haven't saved your document then Word will ask you to save it. It also backs up periodically so that you don't lose your data on a power outage. If those aren't working then it's because you've messed up with the Office installation somehow. Besides it has an option to [create a new backup everytime you save](https://superuser.com/a/656847/241386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but realise it's only for your computer.  If you move computers, the keyboard shortcut will still exist.

1. In *Word 2010*, press **File**, **Options**.
2. Open the **Customize Ribbon** tab.
3. Press the **Keyboard shortcuts: Customize...** button at the bottom of the left-hand list.
4. Select Category **All Commands**, Command **DocClose**.
5. Select the current key **Ctrl+W** and press the **Remove** button at the bottom of the window.
6. Press **Close**, then **OK**.

If you want to see the name of a command that's mapped to a keyboard shortcut, you can type the shortcut in the **Press new shortcut key** box and it will tell you the name of the command that uses that shortcut.  For example, press **Ctrl+N** and it will say "Currently assigned to: FileNewDefault".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way!

Code it's VB code so the format crashes better-look version on my [GitHub page](https://github.com/liusitan/Useful_tools_for_life/blob/master/disable_backspace.bas) and just modify the BuildKeyCode(wdKeyBackspace) to BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl,wdKeyW).

```vb
Attribute VB_Name = "NewMacros"  
Public backspace_disabled As Boolean  

Sub disable_backspace()
KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyB, wdKeyShift, wdKeyControl), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="print_hello_world"
KeyBindings.Add KeyCode:=BuildKeyCode(wdKeyBackspace), KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="empty_function"
End Sub

Public Sub print_hello_world()
Dim aKey As KeyBinding
For Each aKey In KeyBindings
   If aKey.KeyCode = BuildKeyCode(wdKeyBackspace) Then
       If backspace_disabled Then
       MsgBox ("disable_backspace")
       'KeyBindings.Add backspace_fake
       aKey.Rebind KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="empty_function"
       Else
       'FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyBackspace)).Execute
       MsgBox ("enable_backsapc")
       'MsgBox ("bye")
       aKey.Disable
       End If
   End If
Next aKey
backspace_disabled = Not backspace_disabled
End Sub

Public Sub empty_function()
End Sub
```