# Version control in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, version-control, microsoft-office-2016, previous-versions

I currently work on a project which requires data to be written in .on-linear style. As the method is simply trial and error, I've ended up with a folder of Sapara files - one per each version, but it is a bit troublesome.

Since I have only Microsoft Office 2016 (running on Windows 10 64-bit) there is no way to access the SharePoint.

My questions are:

1. Is here a way to store different versions of a document in the same file?
2. What is the best way to store and manage different versions of the same document?

Answer (score 0):

You could synchronize your Word document with OneDrive, meaning specifying the the saving path to OneDrive `File->Save->OneDrive`.
You also might want to look into [this](https://superuser.com/questions/656771/does-word-2013-have-version-control)
and [this](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Recover-a-previous-version-of-a-document-ff1e86fd-44c4-4a84-a1ce-bcaa17d1c127).