# Version Control for Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, version-control

Is there a good version control method for strongly formatted word docs? Ideally something that works with git and shows the diff in an easy-to-view format.

Most of the questions I've seen on this are from 2010 or before.

I'm aware of the following methods:

- Pandocs with git.

  - This was the preferred method, but the diff doesn't always show when a strongly formatted portion of the document is modified.
- TortoiseSVN

  - Shows the diff in word. Diff is more difficult to view than git (3 windows and a sidebar take a lot of space). Requires word to be opened. Larger learning curve than git.
- MagnetSVN

  - I'm cheap.

**Are there any other ways anyone is aware of to use as version control for MS Word?**

Comment: Word documents are saved as binary files, so the diff isn't readable. I'm looking for something that will show the diff between two versions of a document. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: The only real solution (lol) would probably be SharePoint.

Comment: Looking for something local. Sharepoint seems to host the documents remotely, but thanks for the response!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Collaboration? Or the ability to roll back changes made by someone, but still only edited one person at a time?

Comment: @MarkHenderson I'd like to achieve an easy-to-view way of tracking changes. Word already has a feature to track changes to a document, but that becomes unreadable after a certain amount of edits. So a way of specifying that you want to see changes between two instances of the document (viewing the diff). Having the ability to roll back changes is also a factor.

Comment: My suggestion is to use cloud file syncing system like Dropbox, Google Drive, or BOX. As long as the item is being synced, all of the ones mentioned keep a history of revisions/copies that you can then revert back in time. Unfortunately, these systems don't have a easy way to see the difference between versions (as far as I know), but you can use the old and new copies and compare them using word: Tools Menu > Track Changes > Compare Documents.

Comment: Word already have its own version control [Does Word 2013 have version control?](https://superuser.com/q/656771/241386). It also supports [tracking changes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Track-changes-in-Word-197ba630-0f5f-4a8e-9a77-3712475e806a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question and one I have been looking for a solution to as well...

The best I have found thus far is to [download Writage](http://www.writage.com/) (which requires Pandoc - all free), an add-on for Microsoft Word, that converts Word Documents into markdown, then upload the markdown to your host (e.g. github, bitbucket).

Not ideal, but it works.

Ohh, and this is a bit of work ([Word Diff](http://ben.balter.com/2015/02/06/word-diff/)), but ideally what things should look like I think.